# Error when running a main report using a subreport twice on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have an issue when trying to execute a report which is using a subreport twice but with different parameters.

For exemple, I have a main report which is displaying technical specifications for different catégories.

Main report :

- Subreport 1 ( parameter : 'Printer')
- Subreport 1 ( parameter : 'Screen')

It's working when executing it in the Studio but when I publish it on the server and try to execute it, I get an error : "An error occured, please contact your administrator".

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you did into the logs and get us a little more info on the error?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have more info. It doesn't create logs when the problem occurs...

Comment: well it may only show that in the browser, but usually in the log files wherever they are being stored there is a full trace

Comment: I get this `62.210.222.159 - - [23/Mar/2016:16:24:28 +0100] "POST /report/flow.html?_flowExecutionKey=e3s3&_flowId=viewReportFlow&_eventId=navigate&pageIndex=1&decorate=no&confirm=true&decorator=empty&ajax=true HTTP/1.1" 200 35168
62.210.222.159 - - [23/Mar/2016:16:24:28 +0100] "POST /report/getReportComponents.html HTTP/1.1" 500 200`

Comment: that looks like your `access.log` there should also be an `error.log`

Comment: I only have access.log in my tomcat log directory ...

Comment: are you looking in `/var/log/tomcat7/` if you are running on the newer version they should be in there

Comment: you can also try this http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-install-guide/v561/jasperreports-server-log-files make it log everything

Comment: Here is where the logs should be for `JasperReports` server http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tip-location-log-files-jasperserver